# How to update the custom changes on the phonegap plugin

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I installed the phonegap plugin(think anyone) from the github. I did some customization over the plugin java file (android platform). Then I take build but the changes are not applied on the build. So how can I apply my custom changes on the build.

Comment: Are you building your project locally from the command line or using a remote build service?

Comment: And if locally, where did you make the changes to the Java file? In `plugins/`, `platforms/android/src/` or elsewhere?

Comment: It's local build, I just ran the `cordova build android` command. I have not changes the file under platforms instead I changed the file under `plugins/`

Comment: fork the plugin, make the changes and install your fork